# maximum number of homogeneous linearly independent equation over $\mathbb{F}_{2^m}$

Tags: linear-algebra, finite-fields, cryptography

In Field $\mathbb{F}_{256}$ we are given homogeneous equations in 255 variables from the field. It is said that maximum number of linearly independent such equations we can get are 247. Why ?

To be more general,

In Field $\mathbb{F}_{2^m}$ we are given homogeneous equations in 2^m-1 variables from the field. It is said that maximum number of linearly independent such equations we can get are $2^m -m-1$. Why ?